# how to update the uuid package after react was ejected

Tags: reactjs, uuid

I ejected my react project and now when I build my project I get this message:

```
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
```

How do I update this package? I can't find it in `package.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out you just have to delete `package-lock.json` and then run `npm i` which will reinstall everything again.